# Two ajax call for two forms, latter not working

Tags: ajax, forms, post

I've tried everything. The form posts fine when not using Ajax, I switch the places so it would be first, I deleted everything and just gave it an alert to show when clicking submit... I can't pin-point the problem.
The second ajax just won't submit!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#writeform').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'from': $('input[name=from]').val(),
            'to': $('input[name=to]').val(),
            'textbox': $('input[name=textbox]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: formData, 
            dataType: 'json',
                        encode: true
        })

            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// ajax the login
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loginform').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'username': $('input[name=username]').val(),
            'pass': $('input[name=pass]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: formData, 
            dataType: 'json',
                        encode: true
        })

            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function loadLogDiv(){
   $("#logfunction").load("login.php");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
 });
   loadLogDiv();
   setInterval( loadLogDiv, 4000);
});
```

Heres the page itself:

```
<div id="loginpage">
    <form id="loginform" action="login.php" method="POST">

        <div id="username">
            <label for="username">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" />
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>


        <div id="pass">
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>
        <input type="submit">Submit</input>
    </form>
    <div id="logfunction"></div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
    <form id="writeform" action="process.php" method="POST">

        <div id="from">
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <select name="from">
            <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_name FROM `users`");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['user_name'] . "'>" . $row['user_name'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>

        </div>


        <div id="to">
            <label for="to">To</label>
            <select name="to">
            <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_name FROM `users`");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['user_name'] . "'>" . $row['user_name'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>

        </div>


        <div id="textbox">
            <label for="textbox">Text</label>
            <input type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="text" />

        </div>

        <input type="submit">Submit</input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 document.ready?  Try remove the second, and put the content in the first document.ready

Comment: Didn't work. But thanks!

Comment: could you post your html too?

Comment: I will but i don't think the problems there, because when i use the forms without ajax it works fine

Comment: When you say wont submit (the login ajax), you mean you cant enter the handler and do an alert.  Or that the ajax portion does not execute?

Comment: The ajax portion doesn't execute. I tried entering the handler and giving an alert and it worked fine.

Comment: abit hard to test.  try adding the `function loadLogDiv(){
   $("#logfunction").load("login.php");
}` inside a document.ready function